# Move Build definition into sub folder

Tags: java, build, move, rtc, build-definition

**The situation:**

I have created a build definition in RTC using java and it is creating inside the root directory. But the definition has to be created inside a sub-directory of builds folder.
To be more clear I want to create build definition inside *Definition/tools/B1/check*, but it is creating inside *Definition*.

```
if(!isFolderAvailable){
buildFolder=BuildItemFactory.createBuildFolder();
buildFolder.setName(folderName);//folderName gives the required subfolder
buildFolderHandle=(IBuildFolderHandle) buildFolder.getItemHandle();
ClientFactory.getTeamBuildClient(repo).save(buildFolder,new NullProgrssMonitor());
}
```

**What I use for moving:**

```
ClientFactoy.getTeamBuildClient(repo).moveItemsToFolder(definitionHandle,buildFolderHandle, new NullProgressMonitor());
```

I either wanted to create the build definition into the sub folder or i need to move it into the sub folder from root folder. Please suggest the steps to be done if anyone faced the issue.